# how to install numba and link to llvm & llvmlite to import it in Python27

Tags: python-2.7, numba

When I am trying to run python file .py that uses numba it gives me the below error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Myfile.py", line 16, in <module>
 import myfile2 as m
 File "C:\myfile2.py", line 8, in <module>
  import numba
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from . import config, errors, runtests, types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numba\config.py", line 11, in <module>
  import llvmlite.binding as ll
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  from .dylib import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\dylib.py", line 4, in <module>
  from . import ffi
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\llvmlite\binding\ffi.py", line 50, in <module>
   raise e
  WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I've tried to isntall numba from command propmt as below :

```
  pip install numba
```

but it gives me a message that it already exists before

```
  Requirements already satisfied...........etc
```

so could anyone help me to fix this error ? also How to install numba and link it with llvm and llvmlite ?

Comment: What LLVM and LLVMlite versions do you have/use? And which numba version was installed?

Comment: for llvmlite I uninstalled and reinstalled it and it is version 0.20 but i don't know llvm @MSeifert

Comment: But you do have LLVM, right? If not, that would be an obvious explanation for the exception. :)

Comment: I've searched the folder site-packages but i don't found it, and I tried to install it using pip it gives me connection error I am searching for .whl for llvm i found this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/llvmpy/0.12.7
is it llvm ?

Comment: No, that's just the Python bindings for LLVM. [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) has nothing to do with Python so you won't find it in your site-packages. You have to check which LLVM version should be installed and linked to your LLVMlite.

Comment: Maybe you should do yourself a favor and just use conda to install numba. That's trivially easy compared to setting up LLVM, LLVMlite and numba yourself (correctly). At least if you don't have much experience with building and linking libraries.

Comment: forgive me for my little experience in python i am just a beginner, so can i install conda from python 27 command prompt or i have to install anconda it will not be linked to python 27 as I have installed many libraries in python 27 ?

Comment: No, you can't install conda into your existing python environment. You would use conda or anaconda to have a separate python installation. That means you need to install all "extra" packages again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uninstall the python and re-install it again 
and install the below packages in order

```
 pip install scikit_learn
 pip install numby+mkl
 pip install scipy
 pip install  numba
 pip install  matplotlib
```

also I've installed mini conda and it is working fine as well